# xml file in coldfusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I am working on an xml file using coldfusion. I need to count the number of occurence of a certain segment. for example I want to know how many segment 'user' are present in the file.

first of all I parsed the file:

```
<cfset myParsedFile = XmlParse("#LocalPath#/#FileName#")>
```

then I have to do a certain process on each occurence of the segment

```
<cfloop index = 'i' from = '1' to = '#Nboccurence#'>
```

Can anyone know how can we get the number of occurence of a segment (Nboccurence)?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the schema of your XML file, it may be a case of getting the arrayLen(myParsedFile.xmlRoot.xmlChildren), or you might have to perform an xmlSearch and get the arrayLen() of that...

Comment: Post a sample and this would be an easy question. If you have a node with multiple "user" nodes beneath it then all you need is to examine Arraylen(nodeWithUserInIt). @leigh 's example below gives you a way to set that node to a variable to examine, but if your xml is already in an object you may not need to do that. Dump the file (using cfdump) and then figure out the syntax.

Comment: (Edit, posted too soon) Agreed. It depends on the actual xml. Note, you will get faster and more accurate answers if you include all of the necessary information in the question, in this case a sample of the xml as Mark suggested :) See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by reading the documentation on [xmlSearch](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-t-z/xmlsearch.html). If you pass in an xml document, and the path of the elements you want to find, it returns an array of matching nodes.

```
<cfset results = XmlSearch(yourXMLObject, "/path/to/user")>
<cfoutput>Nodes found = #arrayLen(results)#</cfoutput>
```

Use ArrayLen on the returned array to get the number of nodes found. Though if you simply need to iterate through the elements, you can use an array loop instead:

```
<cfloop array="#results#" index="node">
    ... do something with the current node 
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Leigh!! Wonderful!!